# Optimal Strategy for 29 card game

Tags: probability, card-games

I recently played an interesting card games called 29 and was trying to figure the optimal strategy for the same.
Here's the wiki link for the game
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twenty-eight_(card_game)

Is there a mathematical explanation for an optimal bidding?
Also, what could be the best possible strategy for any set of cards (8 cards per player) that a player gets?

Comment: Why not describe the game here? Not sure people are going to go elsewhere to learn about it...

Comment: At a quick glance,  it looks like a stripped down form of Bridge.  Partners,  bidding for trump and so on.  As such,  it is wildly unlikely that there is an easily described "best" strategy that applies to all cases.

Comment: 28 or 29 ?.....